# Execute iconv inside java application

Tags: java, iconv

I want to convert a big csv file from gb2312 encoding to UTF-8 encoding.
Here is the code I used:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                String.format("iconv -c -f %1$s -t %2$s %3$s > %4$s",
                        sourceEncoding, targetEncoding, source, target));
        process.waitFor();
```

The problem is the proccess.waitFor() method never ends. It looks like the iconv is waiting my input like call it from command line and give no args. But from another session of the terminal. I can see the iconv running with correct parameters.

```
root     16729  0.0  0.1 164076   812 pts/0    S+   23:00   0:00 iconv -c -f gb2312 -t utf-8 20110525.csv > 20110525.utf8.csv
```

The command "iconv -c -f gb2312 -t utf-8 20110525.csv > 20110525.utf8.csv" works correctly if I enter it manually from the terminal. But it doesn't work if I call it from java.

The start directory of two way I call the iconv have the same start directory.

Comment: Note that you should not need to call `iconv` from Java, as that functionality is built-in in Java (unless you need a rare, unsupported encoding or its transliteration feature). This would help avoid [the `Runtime.exec()` mess](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirection sign (`>`) is shell/cmd feature, not java, you cannot use it when executing a process from java.

You can grab the OutputStream of the process (`InputStream is = process.getInputStream()`) and save it to file.

Answer (score 3):

As MByD said, the redirection sign is a shell feature.

However, instead of grabbing the OutputStream you could instead execute bash from Java:

```
... .exec("bash -c 'iconv -c -f gb2312 -t utf-8 20110525.csv > 20110525.utf8.csv'")
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. Instead I decide to use the "-o" switch as work around.